# Bootstrap modal window getting stuck

Tags: spring-mvc, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

In my application I have a Bootstrap modal window. In this modal window I am submitting a spring form with jquery ajax post method like below.

```
function test(){
var path=getContextPath()+ "/save.do";
$.ajax({
    url : path,
    type: "POST",
    async : false,
    data: $("#testForm").serialize(),
    statusCode: {
        400: function(xhr) {
            alert("HI");
            alert(xhr);
            $("#testDiv").html(xhr);
        },
        200: function(xhr){
            //do something
        }
      }
});
}
```

I want to render the response in testDiv in case of 400 error code. But whenever response code is 400 then Modal window is getting stuck and shows nothing.